# trouble with cisco wireless lan - netgear switch

Tags: cisco, wifi, netgear

i have a couple cisco ap's (air-lap-1141n-a-k9) that are not communicating with the wlc (cisco 2500 series, ver. 7.0.116) through a netgear switch (FS726TP).

originally everything worked as it should, then i was made aware the guest access was not able to obtain an ip (it is on a separate subnet than the switch/ap's/wlc) but the regular wireless vlan was working fine. i rebooted the switch and the ap's and now they arent being recognized by the wlc at all. there have been no changes to configs anywhere in the chain.

the ports the ap's are connected to are tagged for egress on the guest vlan.

removing tagged egress on the native vlan allows the AP's to reach the wlc at which point i can re-tag the ports and obtain connectivity on the native vlan but am still unable to grab an ip off the guest vlan.

Answer (score 1):

Lightweight Cisco AP's require native vlan access for their management connection and tagged vlans for any H-REAP networks.

On a Cisco switch this would be configured by setting the 'native' vlan on the trunk, on a Netgear it could be native or PVID depending on syntax.

Comment: And the downvote is for?

Comment: I downvoted you by accident... was viewing this question on my smartphone.... I have upvoted you elsewhere to remedy the situation as I cannot retract the original downvote now...

Comment: Ah, thanks for the fix-it vote.  I was worried I was wrong and didn't see how.